# Iterate through a contacts properties using outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I want to iterate through a contacts properties and add those that contain the word "Number" to a list with the value, i tries using reflection but it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace DuplicateNumbers
{
    public class ContactService
    {
        public ContactItem Contact { get; private set; }

        private IDictionary<string,string> phoneNumbers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public ContactService(ContactItem contact)
        {
            Contact = contact;
        }

        public IDictionary<string,string> PhoneNumbers
        {
            get
            {
                if(phoneNumbers.Count == 0)
                {
                    PopulatePhoneNumbers();
                }
                return phoneNumbers;
            }
        }

        private void PopulatePhoneNumbers()
        {
            _ContactItem ci = Contact as _ContactItem;
            MemberInfo[] members = ci.GetType().FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.Instance, (m,criteria) => true, null);
            foreach (var info in members)
            {
                if(info.Name.Contains("Number"))
                {
                    phoneNumbers.Add(info.Name,info.Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(info);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what the problem is? And there's no actual question here.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-properties)This seems to be able to access the ContactItem properties.

Comment: [This seems to be able to access the contacts properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Try using MAPI CDO.

Here's a microsoft site that might get you started: [How to use CDO to read MAPI Addresses](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;179083)

Here's some MAPI Blogs to help as well:

- [Steven Griffin](http://blogs.msdn.com/stephen_griffin/)
- [Matt Stehle](http://blogs.msdn.com/mstehle/)

Answer (score 0):

Of cause it doesn't work - it's a COM object. You should use the properties from CDO space.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be able to access the Outlook.ContactItem properties.
[Enumerating Outlook ContactItem properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-properties)