# Enumerating Microsoft Outlook Contacts

Tags: c#

I have the following code to enumerate all the email address of my contacts but I am not able to do so with the exception point at this line

```
 Outlook.ContactItem oAppt = (Outlook.ContactItem)oItems;
```

Could someone help me out so that I can enumerate all the email address of my contacts in Microsoft outlook ?

```
namespace RetrieveContacts
{
    public class Class1
{
     public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

            Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

            Outlook.MAPIFolder oContacts = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

            Outlook.Items oItems = oContacts.Items;

            Outlook.ContactItem oAppt = (Outlook.ContactItem)oItems;

            for (int i = 0; i <= oItems.Count; i++)
            {
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\EmailAddress.txt");
            file.WriteLine(oAppt.Email1Address);
            file.Close();
            }
            oNS.Logoff();

            oAppt = null;
            oItems = null;
            oContacts = null;
            oNS = null;
            oApp = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Exception.txt");
            file.WriteLine(e);
            file.Close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerating Outlook ContactItem properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing Outlook's object model by heart I'd guess that `Outlook.Items` is a *collection* of `ContactItem`s and thus cannot directly be cast to a single `ContactItem`.  Other concerns:

- You're creating and writing to your file within the loop, so it would get overwritten each time
- You need to validate that the item *is* a `ContactItem` or your cast will throw an error.
- the file access should be in a `using` block so it gets closed automatically if an Exception is thrown
- Your for loop is going from `0` to `Count` when it should be going from `0` to `Count-1` if the collection is 0-based

Try changing your loop to something like this:

```
Outlook.Items oItems = oContacts.Items;
using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\EmailAddress.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < oItems.Count; i++)  // Note < instead of <=
    {
        // Will be null if oItems[i] is not a ContactItem
        Outlook.ContactItem oAppt = oItems[i] as Outlook.ContactItem;

        if(oAppt != null)
            file.WriteLine(oAppt.Email1Address);
    }
}
file.Close();
oNS.Logoff();
```

Comment: I tried your above solution but it gave me the following exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Array index out of bounds.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Items.get_Item(Object Index)

Comment: Yes I did,I copied and paste your section. :)

Comment: Then I would Debug it and see where precisely the error occurs.  My first guess is that the collection is 1-based instead of 0-based.  In that case you would loop from `1` to `Count`.

Comment: Yes the collection is indeed 1-based:  The index for the Items collection starts at 1, and the items in the Items collection object are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.