# Add Existing Contact to User's Contacts

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

We have a set of public contacts the company maintains, but the users only deal with a portion of them so they have copies of them in their local lists. These get out of date. I want to overwrite the information of the local contacts from the public contacts, but can't find an easier way of doing that other than creating the `ContactItem` and then manually setting each property to the values from the public. Is there an easier way of adding existing contacts to the local list?

What I'm currently doing

```
// Get the public folder for the contacts
session = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"); // Application is Outlook
sessionFolders = session.Foldeers;
publicFolders = sessionFolders["Public Folders"];
publicContacts = publicFolders["Public Contacts"];
publicContactsItems = publicContacts.Items;

localContacts = session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFoldes.olFolderContacts);
localContactItems = localContacts.Items;

for(int p = 1; p <= publicContactItems.Count; p++)
{
    var pContact = publicContactItems[p];
    // Search for the contact in the users local list
    for(int l = 1; p <= localContactItems.Count; l++)
    {
        var lContact = localContactItems[l];
        if(publicContact.Email1Address == localContact.Email1Address)
        {
            // Copy information. 
            // DOING localContacts.Items.Add(publicContact) DOES NOT WORK!
            // lContact = pContact doesn't work either.
            // lContact.FirstName = pContact.FirstName; lContact.Save(); does
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's best in the "copy information" section. I could delete the current contact and create a new one with `Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olContactItem)` or I can use the current item, overwrite the properties and save. There are a lot of properties either way though.

EDIT: I may not have added enough information. The `ContactItem` is an Outlook class, not a object created by me. All of this code is in an Outlook Add-in. I've added more code to show this.

EDIT NUMERO DOS: Using @ext0 answer and another question for reference I was able to solve it.

the slight modificatoin to @ext0 answer

```
if (lContact.Email1Address == pContact.Email1Address)
{
    var lProperties = lContact.ItemProperties
    var pProperties = pContact.ItemProperties
    for (i = 0; i < pProperties.Count; i++) // ItemProperties goes back 0 index, keep it up Microsoft!
    {
        try { lProperties[i].Value = pProperties[i].Value} 
        catch{}  // Even though Value is read/write, some properties are read-only
    }
    lContact.Save();
}
```

And remember kids! Always release your com objects after use!

Comment: First off, why are you starting at index 1? Enumerable sets in C# start at 0. Also, what exception **exactly** is thrown when you try and run ``localContacts.Items.Add(publicContact)``?

Comment: From the MSDN page of the `Items` object `The index for the Items collection starts at 1, and the items in the Items collection object are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.` The exception doesn't give me an Exception type but the message is "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try agian."

Comment: My apologies. Is it possible to modify the objects in place?

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure what you mean by "modify". Something like this `localContact = publicContact` or `localContact.FirstName = publicContact.FirstName`. The first one doesn't work, the second one does.

Comment: Okay, then I would suggest the solution that I listed below would likely work for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the data in your old contact object using Reflection in order to completely update all of the properties / fields. If you are using fields instead of properties, just replace `GetProperties()` with `GetFields()`. The following code replaces the contents of `oldContact` with all of the property values of `newContact`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Contact oldContact = new Contact{
        name = "John", 
        email = "John@example.com", 
        age = 40
    };
    Contact newContact = new Contact{
        name = "Joshua",
        email = "John@example.com",
        age = 42
    };
    Type contactType = oldContact.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in contactType.GetProperties())
    {
        property.SetValue(oldContact, property.GetValue(newContact));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(oldContact.age);
}

public class Contact
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

This code will print out `42`, as `oldContact` has been updated with the values from `newContact`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I added enough information on my OP. The contact object is an Outlook object and the `GetType()` method from the `localContact` returns `System._ComObject`. I tried it out anyway and it didn't work. :( But, this seems very useful for other things I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: Awsome! Using this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323069/enumerating-outlook-contactitem-propert I was able to solve the differences. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers!